# Display the selected Item in listbox to textbox

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, listbox

I have a `listbox` which stores records of `XML` file. My XMLfile has multiple elements like Name, Destination, employee ID. The listbox would display all the name contents of the XMLfile.

```
<Information>
     <Name>Goutham</Name>
     <Destination>dar</Destination>
     <EmployeeID>da</EmployeeID>
</Information>
<Information>
     <Name>Adam</Name>
     <Destination>ads</Destination>
     <EmployeeID>dwa</EmployeeID>
</Information>
<Information>
     <Name>dwad</Name>
     <Destination>wadwa</Destination>
     <EmployeeID>daw</EmployeeID>
</Information>
```

The listbox displays all the different names like Goutham,Adam,dwad.
Now if I select Goutham in the listbox, I need to display all the details of Goutham on the textbox. How do i do it?

This is my xaml file

```
<ListBox Height="251" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="330,23,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="170"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"   DisplayMemberPath="Name" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="141,42,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="173" Text="{Binding ElementName= listbox1, Path=SelectedItem.Name}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the listbox fills up it should allready work, you just have a typo in the ElementName binding it should be listBox1.

Also if you want all the details not just the Name you could make a converter and leave only SelectedItem in the binding path. The converter would then format the details form the Information instance returning a string to be displayed in the texbox, or just use several textboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to have MultiBinding with StringFormat:

```
    <TextBlock>
        <TextBlock.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{0} {1} {2}">
                <Binding ElementName="listbox1", Path="SelectedItem.Name" />
                <Binding ElementName="listbox1", Path="SelectedItem.Destination" />                                        
                <Binding ElementName="listbox1", Path="SelectedItem.EmployeeID" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </TextBlock.Text>
    </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind ListBox to once specific property say Name & then bind TextBlock to this listbox.  Depending upon your need, you can have individual TextBlocks for each property or a single TextBlock... as shown below...

```
<Window x:Class="ListBoxDataBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:c="clr-namespace:ListBoxDataBinding"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <c:EmployeeConverter x:Key="myEmployeeConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListBox x:Name="lbEmployee">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="248" Height="24" Text="Employee Name" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="248" Height="24" Text="{Binding ElementName=lbEmployee, Path=SelectedItem.Name}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Width="248" Height="24" Text="Employee EmployeeId" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Width="248" Height="24" Text="{Binding ElementName=lbEmployee, Path=SelectedItem.EmployeeId}" />

        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="248" Height="24" Text="Employee Destination" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Width="248" Height="24" Text="{Binding ElementName=lbEmployee, Path=SelectedItem.Destination}" />


        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Width="248" Height="24" Text="Employee Details" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Width="248" Height="24">
            <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myEmployeeConverter}" ConverterParameter="FormatEmployee">
                    <Binding ElementName="lbEmployee" Path="SelectedItem.Name" />
                    <Binding ElementName="lbEmployee" Path="SelectedItem.EmployeeId" />                                        
                    <Binding ElementName="lbEmployee" Path="SelectedItem.Destination" />
                </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

Code behind....

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private List<Employee> _lstEmployees;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainWindow_Loaded);
    }

    void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _lstEmployees = new List<Employee>();
        _lstEmployees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Goutham", EmployeeId = "da", Destination = "dar" });
        _lstEmployees.Add(new Employee { Name = "Adam", EmployeeId = "dwa", Destination = "ads" });
        _lstEmployees.Add(new Employee { Name = "dwad", EmployeeId = "daw", Destination = "wadwa" });

        lbEmployee.ItemsSource = _lstEmployees;
    }
}

public class EmployeeConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string name;

        switch ((string)parameter)
        {
            case "FormatEmployee":
                if (values[0] is String)
                { 
                    name = values[0] + ", " + values[1] + ", " + values[2]; 
                }
                else
                {
                    name = String.Empty;
                }
                break;
            default:
                name = String.Empty;
                break;
        }

        return name;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string[] splitValues = ((string)value).Split(' ');
        return splitValues;
    }
}
```